# Issue with Vote Score in Ideas in Communities

Tags: customer-community, ideas

I am setting up Ideas in a Customer Community and because the Vote Score takes into account the date of the idea, the score decays based on how old the vote it. I understand that the higher the Vote Score the slower the idea score will decay, but is there a way to disable this part of the score? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom component, you can look at the VoteTotal attribute instead of the VoteScore attribute.